# How to get nested element data in json-server?

Tags: json, nested, json-server

I'm building a ToDo list app, and I run json-server to test the app.
Right now I'm having an issue while trying to get certain data from db.json.

```
{
  "lists": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Listeczka"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "TeżListeczka"
    }
  ],
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "list_id": 1,
      "mainTasks": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "content": "This is task",
          "state": "NOTDONE",
          "subtasks": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "content": "This is subtask",
              "state": "DONE"
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "content": "This is subtask",
              "state": "NOTDONE"
            },
            {
              "id": 3,
              "content": "This is subtask",
              "state": "NOTDONE"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "content": "This is task",
          "state": "NOTDONE",
          "subtasks": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "content": "This is subtask",
              "state": "DONE"
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "content": "This is subtask",
              "state": "NOTDONE"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "list_id": 2,
      "mainTasks": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "content": "This is task",
          "state": "NOTDONE",
          "subtasks": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "content": "This is subtask",
              "state": "DONE"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Right now I wish to get subtasks data, so I can delete it from the coresponding mainTask

So If I'm able to get task data from

```
http://localhost:3000/tasks/1
```

I thought something like

```
http://localhost:3000/tasks/1/mainTasks/1/subtasks/1
```

would work, but it doesn't, I tried to get mainTasks data first somehow but with no effect

```
http://localhost:3000/tasks/1?_embed=mainTasks
```

returns empty object with id, list_id and empty mainTasks